# Using mutate across with sprintf

Tags: r

I have a number of columns that I want to show to 2 decimal places using sprintf.
I have difficulty getting this to work with mutate(across)

The first block of code shows the result without using the across function and the 2nd block of code shows my attempt so far but the error message is:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x 'fmt' is not a character vector
i Input `..1` is `across(c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width), ~sprintf(.x, "%0.2f"))`.

Can anyone suggest an amendment?

```
library(tidyverse)
iris%>%
mutate(
  Sepal.Length = sprintf("%0.2f", Sepal.Length),
  Sepal.Width = sprintf("%0.2f", Sepal.Width))

iris%>%
  mutate(across(c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width), ~ sprintf(.x,  "%0.2f")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the first argument of `?sprintf` is `fmt`.  If we pass arguments without name, then the first argument can be assumed as `fmt`

> sprintf(fmt, ...)

```
library(dplyr)
iris%>%
  mutate(across(c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width), ~ sprintf("%0.2f", .x)))
```

-output

```
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1         5.10        3.50          1.4         0.2  setosa
2         4.90        3.00          1.4         0.2  setosa
3         4.70        3.20          1.3         0.2  setosa
4         4.60        3.10          1.5         0.2  setosa
5         5.00        3.60          1.4         0.2  setosa
6         5.40        3.90          1.7         0.4  setosa
...
```

Otherwise specify as named argument while changing the default order

```
iris%>%
  mutate(across(c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width),
     ~ sprintf(.x,  fmt = "%0.2f")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
head(iris)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

`iris` is only to one decimal place, the following `runif` runs are a better example to demonstrate on.

```
set.seed(100)
as_tibble(replicate(4, runif(20, 0, 1))) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(V1, V2), round, 2))
#> Warning: The `x` argument of `as_tibble.matrix()` must have unique column names if `.name_repair` is omitted as of tibble 2.0.0.
#> Using compatibility `.name_repair`.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#>       V1    V2    V3     V4
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1  0.31  0.54 0.331 0.464 
#>  2  0.26  0.71 0.865 0.647 
#>  3  0.55  0.54 0.778 0.961 
#>  4  0.06  0.75 0.827 0.676 
#>  5  0.47  0.42 0.603 0.445 
#>  6  0.48  0.17 0.491 0.358 
#>  7  0.81  0.77 0.780 0.456 
#>  8  0.37  0.88 0.884 0.445 
#>  9  0.55  0.55 0.208 0.245 
#> 10  0.17  0.28 0.307 0.694 
#> 11  0.62  0.49 0.331 0.412 
#> 12  0.88  0.93 0.199 0.328 
#> 13  0.28  0.35 0.236 0.573 
#> 14  0.4   0.95 0.275 0.967 
#> 15  0.76  0.7  0.591 0.662 
#> 16  0.67  0.89 0.253 0.625 
#> 17  0.2   0.18 0.123 0.857 
#> 18  0.36  0.63 0.230 0.775 
#> 19  0.36  0.99 0.598 0.834 
#> 20  0.69  0.13 0.211 0.0915
```

Using `round` is easier and arguably more readable to use in this case.